# Удаление изображения скриптом

Tags: google-apps-script

Нужно скриптом удалить изображение  в определенной ячейке гугл таблицы.

```
function insert_image(){
listActiv.insertImage(url,1,1).setWidth(110).setHeight(110);
}

function delete_image(){
// как удалить?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение
[нашел на англоязычном Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602177/deleting-images-in-google-sheet-via-script-error)

```js
var images = list.getImages();
  for ( var i = 0; i<images.length; i++){
 var img = images[i];
    img.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Отметьте ответ как решение.